# Display two large buttons stretched over the entire screen

Tags: ios, button, layout

I'd like to display just two buttons in my application which should get streched over the entire screen. It should not matter if I use an iphone or ipad. Beside that, the app gets only presented in landscape mode.

I am using the newest version of xcode and storyboards. I found some settings which did sound promising and searched on the internet, but it had no effect on the buttons.

Comment: Share some code what you have tried and not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In storyboard, go to the view controller you'd like to add the buttons to.  Search for uibuttons in the objects on the bottom right and drag and drop them on the view.

Now you need to add the constraints.  Say you want the buttons side by side and spanning across the screen with equal widths.  Hold control down, click the left uibutton, and drag left to the view. Click horizon spacing to left margin.  A blue line will appear. If you click it and view the inspector, you can make sure the horizontal spacing is 0. Do the same for the right uibutton but with the right margin. Next, control drag from the left button to the right button and select equal widths.  And lastly you can control drag to from the left button to itself and select height to fix the height.do the same for the right button.  You will need to also provide a y position for the buttons by control dragging up to view and select vertical spacing from the top margin.

Now whatever size screen, you'll have two buttons, side by side, equal widths, spanning the whole screen width. You can modify the constraints as you need.

Note that if you click the buttons and go to the inspector on the right, you can customize the buttons.

**EDIT**

To make the buttons one above the other, I would place both buttons on the screen, but I would start with the constraints of the top button.  When you make the constraints, always keep in mind that the frame (x and y position, and width and height) need to be completely determined by the constraints.  So start with the position.  Control drag from the button up to the main view.  You can select center vertically or vertical spacing from top margin for example to set he y position. Control drag from the button left tot the view and create a constraint to set the x position, like leading space (fixes to horizontal distance between the left margin and the button)

Now the size... For the width you can do a few things. You can control drag from the button to itself and select width. This will fix the width to always be whatever it is in storyboard.  A better way is to control drag right to the main view and select trailing space (fixes the spacing from the button to the right margin). Since you have fixed the x position by fixing the leading space and now fixed the trailing space, there is only one possibility for the width to meet both constraints. Thus it's not necessary to create another constraint for the width.  You can fix the height though.

For the second button, to set the y position, you can control drag from the button to the button above and select vertical spacing to fix the distance between the buttons.  For the x position you can control drag again from the button to the button above and align the left edges of the button.  And for the size, you can control drag again from the button to the button above and make them equal heights and widths. So the second buttons frame is completely determined by the one above.

You can also set the frame of the second button based on the main view similar to the first button, so it really depends on your style.  There are multiple ways of setting the constraints so it really depends on your  preference.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention that I like to buttons one above the other. I dont really get it how to work with contraints - I tried it now for over an hour- but before your answer, I didnt even know they exist. Are you so kind and can please edit your answer to match my new requirement with the two buttons, one above the other. This would be very helpful for me!

Comment: Edited! It's really hard to describe with words.  I would check out stanfords cse 193p on iTunes U. It's free that professor is fantastic.  There is a lecture on these constraints that you'd probably find helpful.

Comment: thank you very much. I followed your instructions and it looks good now. But there ist one more thing: On the right and left are margins and in the bottom is a margin double as big as the ones on the sides. Do you have a solution for this?

Comment: These are probably apple defaults.  If you select the bottom constraint, either by selecting the line in storyboard or by selecting it in the outline on the left, and then look at the inspector on the right, you can change the constraint.  You can change the value (even to a negative number) and you change what the constraint is relative to.